# Find the maximal interval $I$ containing $x = x_0$ on which $f$ is invertible

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inverse-function

$$f(x)=\exp\left(\arctan \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\right)$$

Find the maximal interval $I$ containing $x = \pi$ on which $f$ is invertible, and find the explicit expression of the inverse function, specifying its domain $D$.

I calculated $f'$ and studied the monotoneity of $f$: this function is increasing for $x>0$, thus $f$ is monotonic, hence injective, hence invertible in $(0,+\infty)$.

So $I=(0,+\infty)$, $D=\left\{y\in \mathbb R: y>0,\tan \log y>-1,\tan\log y\ge0\right\}$ and $$f^{-1}=\sqrt{\frac{\tan(\log y)}{1-\tan(\log y)}}$$

Have I made some mistakes?

Comment: A function takes a unique value at any argument, so the $\pm$ sign can't be right.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives both functions as the inverse of $f$

Comment: Yeah but you are searching for an inverse, i.e. the function must map positive numbers to positive numbers. Which sign you should take?

Comment: the one with the plus sign, right?

Comment: WA gives two inverse functions because there are two intervals of monotoneity, am I right?